# How to guess 2nd order ode solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this equation $$ y''+y'\cos x-y\sin x=0 $$ My question is this: do i have to guess some y solution in order complete my answer with $y=y_1c_1+y_2c_2$, or is there some other way? If i have to guess, are there any guidelines how to do that? I just can not see any solutions, thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

The idea here is to realize that $(y\cos x)'=y'\cos x-y \sin x$ so the equation becomes
$$(y'+y\cos x)'=0 \Rightarrow y'+y\cos x = c_1$$
Now you can use the integranting factor $u=\exp\left(\int \cos x dx\right)=e^{\sin x}$ to integrate the equation. We have then
$$\left(e^{\sin x}y\right)'=c_1e^{\sin x}\Rightarrow \\
e^{\sin x}y=c_1\int_0^x e^{\sin v}dv+c_2 \Rightarrow \\
y=c_1e^{-\sin x}\int_0^x e^{\sin v}dv+c_2e^{-\sin x},$$
where the constants $c_1=y'(0)+y(0)$ and $c_2=y(0)$ are determined by the intial conditions.